# Schema Parsing Failed in Solr

Tags: java, mysql, xml, lucene, solr

I am getting Schema Parsing Failed when I start solr. I am trying to import data from mysql using DIH. The data-config.xml and changes in schema.xml are below (and also [on PasteBin here][1]).

data-config.xml:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/abcd" user="root" password="admin"/> 
    <document name="products">
        <entity name="tbl_tweet_data_2011_03_14" query="select * from tbl_tweet_data_2011_03_14"
            deltaImportQuery="SELECT * FROM tbl_tweet_data_2011_03_14 WHERE TweetData='${dataimporter.delta.TweetData}'" 
            deltaQuery="SELECT TweetData,Polarity,TweetID,Retweet,TweetCreatedAt,Reply_tweet_ID,Reply_userID,UserID,UserName,CreatedAt FROM item WHERE CreatedAt &gt; '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'"> 

            <field column="TweetData" name="TweetData" />
            <field column="Polarity" name="Polarity" />
            <field column="TweetID" name="TweetID" />
            <field column="Retweet" name="Retweet" />
            <field column="TweetCreatedAt" name="TweetCreatedAt" />
            <field column="Reply_tweet_ID" name="Reply_tweet_ID" />
            <field column="Reply_userID" name="Reply_userID" />
            <field column="UserID" name="UserID" />
            <field column="UserName" name="UserName" />
            <field column="CreatedAt" name="CreatedAt" />

        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Schema.XML: http://pastebin.com/4rxEEQJk

Error Message: http://pastebin.com/sDxncb6R

As the schema.xml and Error message can't fit in the body, so they have been provided in pastebin

Comment: please post the full schema.xml and error message

Comment: Both Schema.XML and Error Message have been provided in pastebin as they cant fit in the body.

Answer (score 2):

You have a custom unique id field `<uniqueKey>TweetID</uniqueKey>` but there seems to be a reference to the default unique id field `id` hanging around somewhere. I looked over your code but couldn't find anything.

Did you change the unique id field just recently? Does it work when you change the name of the field back to `id`?

Comment: I was earlier using Solr with the default schema and defualt unique id as id and it worked. Since i needed to use my own schema for my project so I modified the schema.xml, data-config.xml according to the schema to be used. So its now giving the error

Comment: Do you still have "old" data in the index? Data you imported when using the default schema? If so, try deleting your index.

Comment: Ya I deleted all the previous index files in /solr/data/index & /solr/data/spellchecker

Answer (score 0):

What version of Solr are you using?

In version 5 the schema.xml comments it says

> Do NOT change the type and apply index-time analysis to the  as it will likely 
>        make routing in SolrCloud and document replacement in general fail.

The original id is of type 'int', could you change the TweetID type to 'int'?